# Why is brace expansion not supported?

Tags: shell, brace-expansion

Do I have to do any configuration to start brace expansion? When I run `mkdir {1..10}`, it just creates a dir naming `{1..10}`.

Comment: `mkdir {1..10}` works for me, it creates ten dirs.

Comment: I advise to add `echo ${SHELL}` to render this question able to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While brace expansion like `{1,2}` originates in `csh` in the late 70s, and found its way to Bourne-like shells in `bash`/`zsh`/`pdksh` in the late 80s, early 90s, the `{n1..n2}` variant came later first in `zsh` in 1995 (2.6-beta4).

`bash` copied it in 2004 (3.0) and `ksh93` in 2005 (`ksh93r`).

Probably the shell you're trying this in is neither of those or is an older version of `bash` and `ksh93`.

Comment: We should as about what kind of shebank shell he used. /me suspects it's `#!/bin/sh`...

Comment: @polemon, That would not necessarily help. For instance, on some systems `/bin/sh` is `bash` or `ksh93`.

Comment: I actually think it would: depending on the invocation, shells invoked as `/bin/sh` **act** as the historic `sh` (it's what the bash man page says anyway). Haven't checked `ksh`'s man page, but I'm sure it'll behave accordingly.

Comment: @Stephane Chazelas. Yes I am using the very old RH9. Could you tell me how to check bash version?

Comment: @polemon, you really confused me. Doesn't the shebang line appear inside a script file? But I ran the `mkdir` just on command line.

Comment: @user43312 sorry, I didn't mean to. It was unclear, whether you're referring to something used inside a script or directly from the shell. Errors like this usually creep up in shell scripting, due to the different shells being used as interactive shell and as scripting interpreter.

Comment: @user43312: why are you still using RH9?  It has been unmaintained for many many years.  AS Stephane wrote it is a feature of recent bash versions.  So it's very unlikely that your bash version supports it.  You can check the version using bash --version.  And just to be sure check if you are running a bash shell by checking the $SHELL variable or simply running ps.  To use this feature you might try to start a zsh shell (`zsh`) first.  Anothher workaround would be to use something like "mkdir $(seq 1 10)".

Comment: @polemon You've misunderstood what bash does when invoked as sh -- it runs in POSIX mode, it doesn't mimic another shell. http://sprunge.us/dbYL

Comment: @ChrisDown It kinda clearly says that in the man page: "If bash is invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well." http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Comment: @polemon *The startup behaviour* of another shell (ie. which files it sources upon startup), not mimicry of another shell.

Comment: @ChrisDown: "while conforming to the POSIX standard as well", which changes some things in the way bash behaves

Comment: @OlivierDulac Right, but that's not mimicry of another shell, it's just compatibility fixups. The changes are fairly minor.

Answer (score 4):

`{x..y}` Range brace expansion is implemented in bash 3.0-alpha. To help us and yourself, please show your `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` output.

Then the answer:  If  `mkdir {1..10}` creates a dir with the name `{1..10}` then you are using a bash version prior `bash 3.0-alpha`. In that case you can use a for loop construction as:

`for ((i=1;i<=10; i++)); do mkdir "$i"; done`

Answer (score 1):

Check your Bash version:

```
$ bash -version
GNU bash, version 4.1.7(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

Also check that `mkdir` hasn't been aliases in some strange way:

```
$ alias |grep mkdir
alias md='mkdir'
```