# Quickest way to rename files, without retyping directory path

Tags: rename, mv

I know how to rename files in Unix:

```
$ mv ~/folder/subfolder/file.txt ~/folder/subfolder/file.sh

     ^-------this part------^    ^------this part-------^
```

It takes too long time to repeat `~/folder/subfolder/file` twice.

Is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

If your shell [supported](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92819/38906) [Brace Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) (works with `csh`, `tcsh`, `ksh`, `zsh`, `bash`, `mksh`, `lksh`, `pdksh`, `yash` with *brace-expand* enabled by calling `yash --brace-expand` or set in interative shell with `set -o brace-expand`, or `fish`):

```
mv ~/folder/subfolder/file.{txt,sh}
```

Comment: simple is the best!

Comment: awesome use of expansion in shell brilliant!

Comment: It _is_ awesome, but really cryptic. It works but at the first glance I would think it does something different: moves two file somewhere. I don't think this is a great idea, especially since there is a much better solution using `rename`.

Comment: @tohecz: Why is it cryptic? It's a feature of shell and every one can know it by reading shell man page. And I don't think `rename` is a better solution because `rename` never ask you to override the existing file or not.

Comment: @Gnouc you're the man.

Comment: This worked in Ubuntu 18 without needing to enable any extensions.

Comment: using this, how would I rename `~/fruits/bananas_and_mangos` into `~/fruits/pineapples_and_mangos` ?

Answer (score 23):

You can also use `rename` (part of the util-linux package).

```
rename .txt .sh ~/folder/subfolder/file.txt
```

See the [rename man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) for more details.

Comment: +1 This is the clear way how to do it, much better than relying on shells `{a,b}` functionality.

Comment: In some Linux distros (such as Ubuntu), `rename` is an entirely different, perl-based program. There, you would use `rename 's/txt$/sh/' ~/folder/subfolder/file.txt`.

Comment: On Debian (and Ubuntu), there is also `mmv`.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor `mmv` doesn't work in Ubuntu. Even after installing using sudo apt, this command just hangs and doesn't do anything.

Comment: @ShitalShah how did you call it? What arguments?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Deinstall mtools.

Comment: @jofel use your words.

Answer (score 10):

All the above are good.  This would also work :

```
( cd ~/folder/subfolder && mv file.txt file.sh )
```

Comment: No. It doesn't work for me!

Comment: It will work if you remove the `sudo` part.

Comment: @Cthulhu Yes your right. But why doesn't work with `sudo`?

Comment: @HamedKamrava Probably because with `sudo` it interprets `~` as the root's home directory.

Comment: You can `sudo` the `mv`, but not `cd`. See why cd is a shell built in. And you can not `sudo` the `(`

Comment: shame that the autocomplete would not work for the name of the file

Answer (score 8):

No. You need to give the full path to the file in order to rename it. The only alternative is to move into the target folder before running the `mv`:

```
cd ~/folder/subfolder/
mv file.txt file.sh
```

Alternatively, you could write a little function that renames the file in the target directory. For example, add these lines to your shell initialization file (`~/.bashrc` if you are using `bash`):

```
lmv(){
    _path=$(dirname -- "$1")
    _target="${_path%/}/$2"
    mv -- "$1" "$_target"
}
```

Then, open a new terminal or just run `source ~/.bashrc` to re-read the init file and you can do:

```
lmv ~/folder/subfolder/file.txt file.sh
```

Comment: +1 for `lmv()` function. I didn't know that :)

Comment: @HamedKamrava nobody knew it. I just wrote it, it's not anything standard.

Comment: I know. I mean I didn't know I can write my own function!

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand the usefulness of cuonglm's answer (NOT to take any credit as I love his solution) and his answer is a correct one.

The use case is that we often want to mv a file in a remote location (the real issue),
e.g. /folder/subfolder/configFile.dat TO configFile.dat.orig

This form of the command **adds a file extension** (not replacing the original extension)

```
mv ~/folder/subfolder/file.txt{,.orig}
```

Explained: "{,.orig}" means replace (nothing) on the end of the file name with (something) ".orig"

OR to **remove a file extension** (reverse the rename)

```
mv ~/folder/subfolder/file.txt{.orig,}
```

Note: Still on topic for "Quickest way to rename files without retyping the dir path"

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you use `bash`, you do `sudo pushd ~/folder/subfolder/ && sudo mv ./file.txt ./file.sh && popd`.

Which is actually bigger and may fail if you lost access permissions to the original directory when you did the `popd`.

Comment: What's the point of `pushd` and `popd` here? How is this better than `cd ~/folder/subfolder/ && sudo mv file.txt file.sh`?

Comment: The point is, that you are after the command back in the folder you started, not in any subfolder. An alternative to `pushd` `popd` is to use `cd` and go back with `cd -`.

Comment: The questioner seemed to state an intention not to change the working directory, and `popd` is better than `cd ../../`, when available.

Comment: Use `(cd /path/to/there && mv x y)` then (with a subshell)

Comment: You really should not put `sudo` before `pushd`. So the full command should be `pushd ...dir && sudo mv old new && popd`. As an alternative, one could do `(cd ...dir; sudo mv old new)` because running in subshell will take care of directory changes automatically.