# What's the difference between 'rename' and 'mv'?

Tags: rename, mv

It's not completely clear to me, but what is the difference between `mv` and `rename` (from `util-linux-ng 2.17.2` as `/usr/bin/rename`)? Are there advantages of one over the other beyond `rename` accepting regular expressions and `mv` doesn't? I believe `rename` can also handle multiple file renames at once, whereas `mv` does not do this.

I couldn't find a clear indication in their `man` pages what else sets them apart or through some investigation on my own.

Comment: Let's make sure we're talking about the same things; what are the outputs from `type -a rename` and `rename --version` ?

Comment: @JeffSchaller It's more of a curiosity on my part, but on one of my *nix machines I get `rename is /usr/bin/rename` and `rename (util-linux-ng 2.17.2)` respectively.

Comment: There are a [few different renames out there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames-prename-rename-file-rename), and it could have been an alias/function/script, so I just wanted to make sure we knew what it was. Thank you! Please feel free to edit those outputs into your question.

Comment: @JeffSchaller no worries, actually [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132235/quickest-way-to-rename-files-without-retyping-directory-path#comment260923_132241) was one I just found that showed me `rename` can mean different things in different distros.

Comment: It seems like your question contains its answer.   “What’s the difference between a jet and a tricycle, other than the fact that a jet can ***fly***, and can go several thousand times faster?”    :-)    ⁠

Comment: @G-Man hah I thought that as well, but I was seriously stumped and didn't find any other thread or topic on the matter helpful to me. But I also didn't know about the different rename situation as linked in my earlier comment!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's basically what it says on the lid, for both.

[`mv` is a standard utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/mv.html) to *move* one or more files to a given target. It can be used to rename a file, if there's only one file to move. If there are several, `mv` only works if the target is directory, and moves the files there.

So `mv foo bar` will either move the file `foo` to the directory `bar` (if it exists), or rename `foo` to `bar` (if `bar` doesn't exist or isn't a directory). `mv foo1 foo2 bar` will just move both files to directory `bar`, or complain if `bar` isn't a directory.

`mv` will call the `rename()` C library function to move the files, and if that doesn't work (they're being moved to another filesystem), it will copy the files and remove the originals.

If all you have is `mv` and you want to rename multiple files, you'll have to use a shell loop. There are a number of questions on that here on the site, see e.g. [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19654/170373), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1136/170373), [and others](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=batch%20rename%20files).

---

On the other hand, the various `rename` utilities *rename* files, individually.

[The `rename` from util-linux](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/util-linux/rename.ul.1.en.html) which you mention makes a simple string substitution, e.g. `rename foo bar *` would change `foobar` to `barbar`, and `asdffoo` to `asdfbar`. *It does **not**, however, take a regular expression!*

[The Perl rename utility](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/rename/file-rename.1p.en.html) ([or various instances of it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/170373)) takes a Perl expression to transform the filenames. One will most likely use an `s/pattern/replacement/` command, where the *pattern* **is** a regular expression.

Both the util-linux rename and the Perl rename can be used to move files to another directory at the same time, by making appropriate changes to the file name, but it's a bit awkward. Neither does more than call `rename()` on the files, so moving from one filesystem to another does not work.

As for which `rename` you have, it [may depend on your distribution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275254/170373), and/or what you have installed. Most of them support `rename --version`, so use that to identify which one you have.

Comment: Not only 'regular expression' but function if need it

Comment: @GillesQuenot, well, yeah, you could do e.g. `rename '$_=lc' *` to lowercase filenames. But I think the most common case is to use `s///` (which I mentioned) and the pattern part of it is a regex; I don't think you can use a function there. You could do it in the replacement part, though.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia, That first example in the man page works for me (it just does things differently from the other one). Also, the reason I linked to Debian's manpages is that at least there it's made very clear that the man page for  `rename.ul` is and will be for the util-linux version, and not for any of the others.

Comment: @ilkkachu , do you mind adding an explanation to that first example either in your answer or in a comment. It's different from the example in `man rename` so it would be good to know your understanding of the debian example

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia, I assumed you mean the `rename foo foo0 foo?; rename foo foo0 foo??` example, since that was the only difference between those two man pages I saw. That pair of commands works because the first one adds a zero to the names of each single-digit filename, and after that, the second adds (another) zero each two-digit filename. That second set includes the files renamed by the first command. Using `rename foo foo00 foo?` as the first command also works, it just adds two zeros at one go.

Answer (score 2):

## mv

It's a basic command line designed to do one thing and do it well (Unix philosophy) : *move file(s) or directorie(s)*.

You can hack `STDOUT` & `STDIN`¹ to modify on the fly the destination string, but it's just *not a smart hack*

## rename (Perl's one)

**There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

When people talk about `rename`, we think about this one, not the `ELF` one, less powerful (magic?).

It's not basic, it's Perl. You can pass some Perl's functions inside, and it's extremely powerful.

Consider this example :

You want to *rename* a bunch of files like

```
foobar_1.txt
foobar_2.txt
foobar_3.txt
```

You can prepend zeros to the digits with `sprintf()` like this (using regex, heh, it's Perl :D ) :

```
rename 's/(\d+)/sprintf("%04d", $1)/e' foobar_*.txt
```

Now you have :

```
foobar_0001.txt
foobar_0002.txt
foobar_0003.txt
```

Not really a basic command, isn't it ?

[rename](/questions/tagged/rename) is not really designed to *move dir(s)*, but it can do it :

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/foo/bar/base
$ touch /tmp/foo/bar/base/file
$ rename 's!/tmp/foo/bar/base/file!/tmp/file!' /tmp/foo/bar/base/file
```

## The moved file

```
/tmp/file
```

---

¹ some code we see on `*.stackexchange.*` websites

```
for FILE in `ls *.txt`
do
    mv ${FILE} `echo ${FILE} | sed 's/anything_ugly/anything_still_ugly/'`
done
```

**It's not the way to go**, it's plain buggy, just to explain why to use the right tool at the right moment

Comment: +1 for `sprintf`ing with rename

Comment: Why do you say `stackexchage.*` ?  Is there any `stackexchage.*` other than `stackexchage.com` ?  To partially answer my own question, (1)  `stackoverflow.es` is a Spanish-language site that appears to be legitimate, but has no relationship to Stack Overflow.  (2)  `stackexchange.es` is a “Buy this domain” site that uses a certificate registered to `parkingcrew.net`, which appears to be a brazen operation to monetize parked domain names.  (3)  `stackoverflow.ru` uses a certificate registered to `stackoverflow.com` and attempts to redirect to `ru.stackoverflow.com`, but doesn’t do it correctly.

Comment: StackExchange globally: superuser.com unix... Ubuntu...

Answer (score 2):

`mv` simply changes the name of the file (it can also move it to another filesystem or path). You give it an old name and a new name, and it changes the file to the new name or location.

`rename` is used to make bulk naming changes.

Say you had a thousand files, `foo000.log` through `foo999.log` and you wanted to change them to `bar000.log` through `bar999.log`.

With `mv` you'd have to do `mv foo000.log bar000.log`, `mv foo001 bar001.log`, etc. or else write a script.

With `rename` you simply do `rename foo bar foo*.log`, and voila, a thousand files are changed in an instant! Pretty cool.

Check out the `man rename` page again for details.

Answer (score 0):

*mv* moves or renames files and directories and will back them up; *rename* just renames files.

*mv* has more capabilities and options. Look at the switches in the man pages for each to see the differences in capabilities. Let's take a look using *man* in Ubuntu 18.04LTS (your mileage may vary depending on the version of each package):

mv options (omitting help and version)

```
   --backup[=CONTROL]  
          make a backup of each existing destination file  

   -b     like --backup but does not accept an argument  

   -f, --force  
          do not prompt before overwriting  

   -i, --interactive  
          prompt before overwrite  

   -n, --no-clobber  
          do not overwrite an existing file  

  If you specify more than one of -i, -f, -n, only the final one takes effect.  

   --strip-trailing-slashes  
          remove any trailing slashes from each SOURCE argument  

   -S, --suffix=SUFFIX  
          override the usual backup suffix  

   -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY  
          move all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY  

   -T, --no-target-directory  
          treat DEST as a normal file  

   -u, --update  
          move only when the SOURCE file is newer than the destination file or when the destination file is missing  

   -v, --verbose  
          explain what is being done  

   -Z, --context  
          set SELinux security context of destination file to default type
```

rename options  (omitting help and version)

```
   -s, --symlink   
          Do not rename a symlink but its target.  

   -v, --verbose  
          Show which files where renamed, if any.  

   -n, --no-act  
          Do not make any changes.  

   -o, --no-overwrite  
          Do not overwrite existing files.
```

Comment: Define 'more powerful'. Does mv support regex like rename ?

Comment: As the questioner stated, no.

Comment: Wow, what an argument

Comment: Giving credit where credit is due.