# How to trim off specific parts of multiple directory names?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, directory, rename

I have 100 directories within a parent directory (/home/anik/"all my directories") with the following naming structure:

- Zt.isolate1.Spades
- Zt.isolate2.Spades
- Zt.isolate100.Spades

I want to trim off the "Zt." and the ".Spades" part from each of the directory name.

Can you please tell me how can I do that in a loop for all the directories at once?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi Anik and welcome to unix.stackexchange.  If your problem was solved and your question correctly answered, you have the option of checking the green mark next to your favorite answer. This way several things happen: (i) you indicate that a question was satisfactorily answered, thereby signalling to others in the community that the answer is worth consulting, (ii) you reward the answerers by adding points to their karma, (iii) in doing so you show your gratitude and acceptance. -- Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the names and use variable substitutions to delete the unwanted bits.  The following assumes that `$HOME` is `/home/anik` and that this is where your files are located (change `topdir` to some other value if the files are located elsewhere):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

topdir=$HOME

for dirpath in "$topdir"/Zt.*.Spades; do
    [ ! -d "$dirpath" ] && continue

    newdirpath=$topdir/${dirpath#$topdir/Zt.}
    newdirpath=${newdirpath%.Spades}

    if [ -e "$newdirpath" ]; then
        printf 'Can not rename "%s" into "%s", name taken\n' "$dirpath" "$newdirpath"
    else
        printf 'Renaming "%s" into "%s"\n' "$dirpath" "$newdirpath"
        echo mv "$dirpath" "$newdirpath"
    fi
done
```

The expression `$topdir/${dirpath#$topdir/Zt.}` will be replaced by the directory's pathname, but without the `Zt.` in the start of the directory filename.  It does this by removing the prefix `$topdir/Zt.` and then adding `$topdir/` at the start again.

The expression `${newdirpath%.Spades}` expands to `$newdirpath` but removes the string `.Spades` from the end of the value.

I've added `echo` in front of the `mv` command to output the command that would be executed instead of executing it.  Test the code and then remove the `echo` if it looks correct.

Comment: Okay that worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. Just another question: what if I just want to remove only the `Zt.` part? Should I delete the `newdirpath=${newdirpath%.Spades}` from the above code?

Comment: @AnikDutta That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Perl `rename` tool:

```
rename -n 's/Zt\.(.+?)\.Spades$/$1/' /home/anik/Zt.*.Spades
```

(Remove the `-n` to actually rename if you're happy with the output)

---

Check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames-prename-rename-file-rename) to choose the correct `rename` tool.

Comment: Can I use this code in Linux? Sorry if it's a naive question.

Comment: Sure, this is for Linux... but make sure that `rename` is the correct command name. It differs between distributions.

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. The command ran and nothing has changed.

Comment: @AnikDutta, there's the util-linux rename and the various Perl-based ones. Try `rename --version` and see if it mentions `util-linux` or not, and see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275254/170373 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/510583/170373

Comment: Yes, it mentioned util-linux

Comment: If you're running debian (or derivatives like ubuntu, mint, etc), run `apt-get install rename`.   On other distros, find out how to install the perl rename because the rename from util-linux is primitive and nearly useless in comparison.  It may already be installed but called `prename` or `file-rename`.