# Renaming multiple files that contain different numbers

Tags: linux, rename

I have multiple files that have the following format: (note that file corresponds to each file name which is not common).

```
File1_S20.tab
File2_S25.tab
File3_S40.tab
etc.
```

I want to rename them all so they become:

```
File1
File2
File3
etc.
```

Basically removing the `_S$$.tab` part from all the files.

For renaming files, I usually use the rename command as follows: `rename # somethingelse *.tab` (replace `#` by `somethingelse`).

But the only trouble I have is that each file has a different number after the `S`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like you have the util-linux version of `rename`, which doesn't bend to that easily. There's also a Perl-based tool called `rename`. (see: [What's the difference between 'rename' and 'mv'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/510553/170373))

With the Perl rename, if you can get it, that's easy (or add `-n` to see what it would do):

```
rename 's/_S\d+\.tab//' File*.tab
```

(It's relatively simple to implement the rename loop in Perl, but doing it right and safe takes a few lines.)

But you can do it with a loop in the shell:

```
for f in File*.tab; do
    mv -n -- "$f" "${f%%_S[0-9][0-9].tab}"
done
```

(Or `"${f%%_S*.tab}"` to match anything in place of the two digits, or use `shopt -s extglob` in Bash, and then `"${f%%_S+([0-9]).tab}"` to match any number of digits there.)

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't get the Perl-based tool but I used the loop method and it worked!