# How to create files named 'a to z' - any trick?

Tags: shell, files, touch

I need to create 26 files named a to z in single command. I thought `touch` command would be sufficient with the regex, but it doesn't expand `[a-z]` instead it creates a single file with name "[a-z]".

```
$ touch [a-z]
```

Any way to achieve these?

Note:

```
$ bash -version
 GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `bash` (version 3.0 (2004) and above), `ksh` (since ksh93r (2006)) and `zsh` (version 5.0.6 (2014) and above):

```
touch {a..z}
```

(note that only `zsh` supports characters other than ASCII letters and digits, none goes as far as `perl`'s `..` operator which inspired those shells operators).

With other `zsh` version (since 2.2 (1992)):

```
setopt braceccl
touch {a-z}
```

Comment: Just tested it and that works great on Ubuntu.

Comment: bash and zsh and some other shells will expand {a..z} to an ASCII sequence of 26 separate arguments.  Your /bin/sh however might not know about it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. still no success, I am bash 4.3

Comment: cool. it works like a charm. I was giving wrong command. it is `..` and not hyphen.. Thanks

Comment: @SaulOrtega: Yes, of course, that's why I mention only `bash`, `ksh` and `zsh`.

Comment: I do wonder about the logic that led bash, at least, to restrict it to letters, but allow ranges to span between upper and lower case including `[]^_\``.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas: Is this edit conflicted with your one [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92829/38906)

Comment: for zsh braceccl is from 92, {1..5} from 95, {a..z} from 2014. For ksh93, the feature is from 2005, but ksh93r which is the first including it was released in 2006.