# Insert text to file using bash scripts (NOT appending)

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to add text to a file using shell-scripts. 
The solution I know is if you want to insert your text into a newline (appending):

```
echo "mytext" >> myfile.txt
```

what I want to have a continuous text at the end of process.

```
for ((I=0; I <72 ; I++))
  do
    echo "mytext$I, " >> myfile.txt   ????? 
done
```

I want something like:

```
mytext0, mytext1, mytext2, mytext3, ...., mytext71
```

but instead I get:

```
mytext0, 
mytext1, 
....
mytext71
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and output: "a continuous text at the end of the process" is so ambiguous to be meaningless...

Comment: I edited my question, hope it is more clear now...

Comment: `echo` outputs a newline each pass of the loop.  do want `echo -n` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash` (and also shell which [support brace expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92819/38906)), you can do:

```
printf '%s\n' "$(printf 'mytext%s\n\n' {1..71})" | paste -sd', ' - >out
```

In POSIX shell:

```sh
printf '%s\n' "$(
n=1
while [ "$n" -le 71 ]; do
  printf 'mytext%s\n\n' "$n"
  n=$((n+1))
done
)" | paste -sd', ' - >out
```

Comment: so where is myfile.txt in this way?

Comment: @H'H: Added it, replace `out` with whatever name you want.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sure you don't append a newline to the end of the output: just replace `echo` with either `echo -n` or `printf`. I'd recommend the latter as it's more portable.

Comment: You will get the laste element as `mytext71, `.

Comment: I mentioned I want something continuous like this: mytext0, mytext1, mytext2, mytext3, ...., mytext71