# Sorting ls output where files end in numbers

Tags: shell-script, ls, sort

Here is the output of my normal `ls` command:

```
f1  f10  f11  f12  f13  f14  f15  f16  f17  f18  f19  f2  f20  f3  f4  f5  f6  f7  f8  f9
```

So I have 20 files. I need them displayed as :

```
f1  f2 f3  f4  f5  f6  f7  f8  f9 f10  f11  f12  f13  f14  f15  f16  f17  f18  f19  f20
```

Is there any single-line command to this other than writing a script? I am sure some of you must have faced this weird situation. Note: the above is just a sample. In the actual scenario I need a list of all the file names in proper sorted order. (ranging from `f{0..10000}`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fortunately! there is a single-line command

`ls -lav`

should do what you are looking for

Comment: Oh Natural sort! cool.

Comment: Good answer.  To be clear, it's the -v option that answers the question:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html

Comment: thanks for the clarification : )

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `ls`, you can use:

```
ls -v
```

---

With POSIX tools chest:

```
ls | sort -nk1.2 | paste -sd ' ' -
```

---

If you are sure that all files in range existed, [with shells have brace expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92819/38906):

```
echo f{1..20}
```

---

With `zsh`:

```
print -r -- f*(n)
```