# List only files which have a specific character on a position

Tags: files, ls, command

I have 10 files in a dictionary and want to list only files that have an "c" or "z" on position 3 using the ls command. How do I do this?

Comment: s/dictionary/directory/ ?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  What have you tried so far to answer your coursework ?

Answer (score 4):

Simple *globbing*:

```
ls -ld -- ??[cz]*
```

---

- `?` - matches any single character
- `[cz]` - matches one character given in the brackets (character class)

Note that hidden files will not be included.

Comment: @Tigger, that should be fixed by the recent edit (which also fixes the problems with filenames starting with `-`)

Answer (score 0):

Use globbing, each question mark represents a character. Therefore, the answer below indicates that you want anything listed that contains `c` or `z` character as a third occurrence.

```
ls ??{c*,z*}
```

or:

```
ls ??{c,z}*
```

Comment: also note that this require a shell that support brace-expansion, see [Why is brace expansion not supported?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92819/72456)

Comment: Contrary to Roman's approach, that also means expanding too independent globs so is less efficient and in `zsh` or `bash -O failglob`, that would abort the command if *either* of the two globs has no match.

Comment: and in Bash with default settings (`failglob` and `nullglob` not set), this will give an error from `ls` for the nonmatching glob, e.g. if the existing files are `abcde`, `fghij`, `ls` will list `abcde` and give an error for `??z*`. There's really no reason to use braces to single-character alternatives, when brackets already work (like in the other answer). Even if the alternatives did consist of more than one character, ksh-style extended globs would be better (e.g. `??@(c|foo)*`).