# Why grep --include with curly braces fail in subshell?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, subshell

This works in shell:

```
grep -R --exclude-dir=storage --exclude-dir=node-modules --include=*.{scss,css} loader.gif
```

But this fails:

```
sh -c "grep -R --exclude-dir=storage --exclude-dir=node-modules --include=*.{scss,css} loader.gif"
```

It fails without any message, it just can't find any occurrence.

This works:

```sh
sh -c "grep -R --exclude-dir=storage --exclude-dir=node-modules --include=*.scss loader.gif"
```

Why the use of curly braces in `--include=*.{scss,css}` fails?

Comment: because `sh` has no brace-expansion, use for example `bash` or `zsh` or `csh`. see also  [Why is brace expansion not supported?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92819/why-is-brace-expansion-not-supported)

Comment: In a shell that supports brace-expansion you can supply: `--include=*.{s,}css`

Comment: Don't use all those wacky GNU grep options for finding files. Keep your scripts simple and use `find` to **find** files and `grep` to **g/re/p** within files. There are clues in the tools names to their intended use!

Answer (score 2):

Probably because your `sh` is plain POSIX sh (or at least plainer than your login shell), and doesn't support brace expansion. Of Linux systems, this is the case by default in at least Debian and [Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh). If you want to run Bash, run `bash -c` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Because of "time of expansion".

Lets simplify the command:

```
$ echo --include=*.{scss,css}
--include=*.scss --include=*.css
```

As you can see, the braces were expanded by the "present running shell" (probably bash). And the `*` was not expanded as probably there is no file which name start with `--include=` and also ends on `.scss` (or `.css`) in the present directory.

However, in:

```
$ sh -c "echo --include=*.{scss,css}"
--include=*.{scss,css}
```

Two things happen:

- the present running shell (PRS) doesn't expand the braces because they are quoted and are given literally to the next shell `sh -c`.
- the next shell doesn't support brace expansion as leaves them as they are. Printing them with echo.

So, either make the PRS expand the braces:

```
sh -c 'echo "$@"' mysh --include=\*.{scss,css}
```

Which is complex and not the recommended solution. Or, use a brace aware shell:

```
bash -c 'echo --include=\*.{scss,css}'
```

Both `*` are quoted to prevent their expansion.